# What are the consequences of adding a adding queues to existing address bindings in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

My query is for the product Red Hat AMQ 7.X (and I am using 7.2), which is based on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis.

Based on [Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/address-model.html)

You can associate multiple queues to a given address

[image: Point-to-Point with Two Queues]

Assume this configuration is in production and we need an add a 3rd consumer and consequently queue, what considerations would need to be taken in account?

Would the 3rd queue get all the prior messages (guessing no)?

Would the 3rd queue get all the unconsumed messages (guessing no)?

Would the 3rd queue get all the messages published after it was created (guessing yes)?

Would adding the 3rd queue have any consequences on the existing queues and/or consumers?

The sample configuration after adding the 3rd queue

```
<configuration>
    <core>
    <address name="address.foo">
      <anycast>
        <queue name="q1"/>
        <queue name="q2"/>
        <queue name="q3"/>
      </anycast>
    </address>
  </core>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the 3rd queue get all the prior messages (guessing no)?

No.

> Would the 3rd queue get all the unconsumed messages (guessing no)?

No.

> Would the 3rd queue get all the messages published after it was created (guessing yes)?

Yes.

> Would adding the 3rd queue have any consequences on the existing queues and/or consumers?

No.